# Move Objects in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I want to move an Object from one place to another. MOVE, not translate. I mean, when I click on a button (that part is done) that object should start moving and stop in another place.

I've trayed already the tranlateX, Y, Z methods, but they translate the Object instead of actually moving.

This is my function so far, but three.js does it so fast that it feels like a translation.

```
function moveButton{
   for (var i = 0 ; i <= 2000; i++){
     model.translateX(.001);
     model.translateY(.001);
      }
}
```

Anice example of what I want is here:
https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Model-Animation-Control.html
but instead of that, I just want to press one button once and let it move fluently for a while.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in a `for`-loop is not possible because JavaScript is blocking the browser there, its not related to `three.js`.

Use `tween.js` for animation: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/

Comment: The tween.js was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thats fine, I removed the alternatives because they were more of a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `model.position.x +=0.001`. Same for `.y` and `.z`.